# How do I parse XHTML document from Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I have a XHTML document received via Ajax.
How do I get content of `<title>` tag?
I tried invoking `getElementsByTagName()` on XHTML document, but error says variable referencing XHTML document doesn't have `getElementsByTagName()` method.

Comment: Which browsers does this need to work in? Is your your XHTML valid (eg. if you look at responseXML, it actually has content in it)?

Comment: Chrome. it's Chrome extension. i use responseText. Can i use responseXML with xhtml??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your XHTML is valid, you should be able to use responseXML from your XMLHttpRequest to get an XMLDocument representation of your markup.

Alternatively you could try creating a div, and setting the responseText as the div's innerHTML.

Comment: i tried responseXML, i also used indexOf on responseText, so now error says 'cannot call indexOf of null'..

Comment: "creating a div, and setting the responseText as the div's innerHTML" worked!! Thanks!!